# Cruise Control clear case integration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

I am trying to integrate clear case with cruise control.I have sucessfully integrates it ,
but when i check in any changes in clear case the build is not happening automatically.below is my ccnet.config

```
  <sourcecontrol type="clearCase">
  <viewPath>M:\temp_view2\CDMVOB\Cruise</viewPath>
  <branch>main</branch>
  <autoGetSource>false</autoGetSource>
  <useLabel>false</useLabel>
  <useBaseline>false</useBaseline>
  <projectVobName>CDMVOB</projectVobName>
  <viewName>temp_view2</viewName>
  <executable>cleartool.exe</executable>
  <timeout>50000</timeout>
    <!--<modificationset> quietperiod=5</modificationset>-->
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: Can you please show your `<trigger/>` block as well?

Comment: I have not kept any tirgger block , i need the trigger block actually

Answer (score 0):

The CruiseControl config I usually see (like in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=196843) or in [CruiseControl wiki](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/ClearCase)) use:

```
<autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
```

(in order to scan and get the new revisions published by the source control)

Comment: If i make <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource> it will ask for a snapshot view, i am currently doing it through dynamic view

Comment: @user1383839 ok, makes sense. Is there any issue with the other parameters (like a `cleartool.exe` not found?) What does the log or CruiseControl job output log contains?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least this in your project configuration if you want it to [auto-build on changes](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Trigger_Blocks):

```xml
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger />
</triggers>
```